# Por que tengo este error? ValueError: Field 'stock' expected a number but got 'null'

Tags: django, django-models, django-urls

Queria agregar un campo llamado stock en mi base de datos,asi que lo puse en el modelo de la siguiente forma

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class ProductsData(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150) 
    description = models.TextField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='null')
    content = models.TextField()
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(default='null')
    public = models.BooleanField()
    created_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at= models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default="null")
```

Y cuando quiero hacer la migrate,me sale el error del titulo.Por que puede ser?

Probando con esto tambien me da el mismo error

```
stock = models.IntegerField(default=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te da ese error por que un IntegerField no puede tener como default la cadena de texto "null"

El valor por default debe ser un número entero que puede ir desde el -2147483648 al 2147483647

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#integerfield

Comment: Al final despues de probar eso, tuve que ir a migrations a cambiar los valores directamente y aparentemenete funciono,Nose por que ...Me estaba volviendo loco